# Priority Queue Juggling

Tags: scheduling, priority-queue

I have a single collection of items which require periodic updating. The items have a weighting in that some must be serviced more frequently than others. However, I must service all items within a certain time (ie I don't want there to be items that end up never being processed).

If all items had the same weighting, a simple FIFO would suffice. But the higher-priority ones need to be able to cut-in, therefore I reckon a priority queue is indicated. Question is, what determines the priority? I figure it's a function of weighting, and time since last serviced. But how to determine the form of that function so that no item stays at the bottom of the heap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would sort based on their time in the queue then by priority weighting.  On addition of a new item to the queue apply a time based threshold so when the new item is added it cannot be placed higher than those that have exceeded the maximum allowable time in queue.